# Uncaught ReferenceError: req is not defined with cli@1.5

Tags: javascript, angular, production-environment

Found this post that appears to resolve the issues.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8359

Sorry but it is not clear to me what is the next step to fix this issue?

Which version of angular cli should I upgrade to fix this?

Note that this happens in compiling in angular production mode.

Comment: Would be glad for a comment instead of a negative vote

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g angular-cli@1.4.9
```

People in the post generally mention no issues after going to CLI 1.4.9

Also, the Angular verison might need to be dropped down as well if just doing the CLI doesn't work. See jonathanbruno's comment on that page

Comment: Not looking for a downgrade. Can you see a proper solution in that link? I thought we have to upgrade to angular cli 1.6 or later where the uglify plugin has been updated but it is a bit confusing

Comment: One other person mentions upgrading to 1.6 (@angular/cli@1.6.0-beta.0) and that it worked for them. And that was in Nov so there might have been further releases since then. Upgrade as the latest and see if it is resolved.